# Appcelerator. Button on row is not registered when clicked

Tags: appcelerator-mobile

Titanium SDK version: 1.7.0.RC1 
iPhone SDK version: 4.2

I am developing a very simple iOS app in Appcelerator that fetches tweets from Twitter and displays them in a table. Each row/tweet got a button that, if clicked, will add the selected tweet to the database. I also want the user to be able to click the tweet itself too.

What is wrong with this code? It is not responding to clicks on the button. I also need the row to disappear when the button is clicked.

http://pastie.org/2038105

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem solved using the solution found here.

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/120723/button-on-row-is-not-registered-in-event-listener#209636